# How to handle recursion in views(mvc)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I need to recursively iterate over an array in a view and was wondering what are some best practices for this type of situation? I'm trying to avoid building my desired html output in the controller or model.

FYI I'm using the framework codeigniter.

Comment: What do you mean with a 'structure'? Could you provide an example?

Comment: It's easier to answer this question if you show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @Anzeo: When i say structure i meant to say data structure; An array in my case

Comment: In that case, you could try Natebot's solution. If that doesn't work out, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are bound to be varied opinion on how to achieve your end - and much may depend on the complexity of your structure and how you wish to organize your views.

At its simplest you may wish to use PHP iterative statements in your view. This is commonly seen in basic CI examples where the controller passes data to a view, then a foreach loop outputs the array elements or object properties in the view. Some may dislike using PHP in their views (if, for example, they co-develop with designers afraid of PHP's syntax) or wish to employ CI's (or a 3rd party) tempting class instead. However there is nothing wrong with some PHP in your view. It's been pointed out that PHP is a template language already.

Another approach that works for complex views is to use nested views or concatenating views. 
You may load a view which has in it a single iterative statement which in turn loads a view with each iteration. Or conversely you can do this iteration in your controller, and simply concatenate the output of each view, like so:

```
// iterate through a DB result set to create a block of markup
foreach($result_set as $result)
{
  $view_set .= $this->load->view('result_view_1',$result,TRUE); // the third argument allows us to return the output string.
}

// now determine what view will display this bock of markup
$this->load->view('results_page_A',array( 'view_set' => $view_set ));//
```

The advantage of this approach is that your views are reusable by other controllers or actions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try and implement the recursive views as per your "another appraoch"

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is included in the built-in template class. I recently did a project where we wanted to create our views without any native PHP code inside the views. I tested this example in a live page just now, works 100% in CI 2.1.3.

As a specific example, consider this code which displays (with minimal formatting) a series of rooms available at a hotel, and shows, per room, the rate(s) per day for each day of your travel. (2 days, in this example.)

```
{available_rooms}
    <p>{room_type} {total_rate}</p>
    {room_rates}
        <p>${room_rate} {room_date}</p>
    {/room_rates}
    <hr>
{/available_rooms}
```

With out put similar to:

```
1 King Bed 119.98
 59.99 2013-03-23
 59.99 2013-03-24

1 King Bed 119.98
 59.99 2013-03-23
 59.99 2013-03-24

2 Double Beds 139.98
 69.99 2013-03-23
 69.99 2013-03-24

2 Double Beds 139.98
 69.99 2013-03-23
 69.99 2013-03-24
```

I used my controller to pass the data to the template engine like so:

```
$this->parser->parse(/reservations_view', $this->data);
```

This is the data array I used successfully in this example. The array was first assigned to $this->data->available_rooms before $this->data was passed to the parser.

```
> available_rooms > 0 > room_type = 1 King Bed 
> available_rooms > 0 > total_rate = 119.98 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 0 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_type = 1 King Bed 
> available_rooms > 1 > total_rate = 119.98 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 59.99 
> available_rooms > 1 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_type = 2 Double Beds 
> available_rooms > 2 > total_rate = 139.98 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 2 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_type = 2 Double Beds 
> available_rooms > 3 > total_rate = 139.98 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 0 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 0 > room_date = 2013-03-23 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 1 > room_rate = 69.99 
> available_rooms > 3 > room_rates > 1 > room_date = 2013-03-24
```